# iOS: Auto Layout vs autoresizingMask - resizing whole view to fill?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, autolayout

I've got a storyboard which is built using Auto Layout.  Within that storyboard, I'm embedding a `UIViewController` subclass (`ButtonGridViewController`) in several locations, each of which is a different size.  `ButtonGridViewController`'s view is defined in a xib.

What I need is for the entirety of the `ButtonGridViewController`'s view to simply scale-to-fill the view I'm embedding it in.  With the old struts-and-springs method, this was trivial -- just set all the subviews to resize in both directions, and voila, piece of cake.

How do I accomplish the same thing using constraints?  For what it's worth, the xib just contains a main view, which is rectangular, and has 4 subviews - each a button - arranged in a 2x2 grid.  I want everything, including the buttons AND spacing, to scale and/or stretch to fill the view it's going into.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by embed? Are you using container views?

Comment: Container view in one case; in all other cases, just instantiating the ButtonGridViewController and adding its view as a subview to an existing UIView programmatically.

Comment: If there isn't a reason that you can't use container views for all, that would make it a lot easier. The view will automatically fit to the container view.

Comment: Alas, I can't.  It would be possible, however, for me to not use any container views (i.e. always add the view controller's view as a subview to an existing uiview), if that would at least help by making it more consistent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To accomplish the same thing using constraints you need to set the leading, trailing, top and bottom space to the superview to 0.  See below:

```
//load the ButtonGridViewController from a xib
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"..." owner:self options:nil];

//get the view add it
[self.view addSubView:self.myGridView];

//turn off springs and struts
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

//add constraints to fill parent view
NSArray *arr;

//horizontal constraints
arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[vw]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                              views:@{@"vw":self.myGridView}];
[self.view addConstraints:arr];

//vertical constraints
arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[vw]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:@{@"vw":self.myGridView}];
[self.view addConstraints:arr];
```

Comment: Same thing is not working for me. I have same scenario where I am adding a subview to my view. View is in Storyboard and subview is in .xib. WHen I add constraints programmatically like above, I get simultaneous constraints and it breaks...