# Set custom UIView frame in UIViewRepresentable SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I'm trying to use my custom UIView in SwiftUI using UIViewRepresentable and I want my UIView to have the same size as I set in .frame() so that I can use it like this:

```swift
MyViewRepresentable()
.frame(width: 400, height: 250, alignment: .center)
```

For example, I can set a frame as a property:

```swift
struct MyViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    var frame: CGRect
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let myView = MyView(frame: frame)

        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Usage:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyViewRepresentable(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 250))
            .frame(width: 400, height: 250, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

It is not a solution and I wonder how to make it right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `MyView` has correct internal layout (which depends only on own bounds), then there is not needs in external additional limitation, ie

```
struct MyViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return MyView(frame: .zero)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

will be exactly sized below having 400x250 frame

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyViewRepresentable()
            .frame(width: 400, height: 250, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

if it is not then internal MyView layout has defects.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I looked at my code and found that I added MyView subviews in viewDidLoad, not in layoutSubviews.

Comment: Thank you @IreiDev, that did the trick for me too.
Maybe you add this as an answer to your own question, that xould be helpful

Comment: Thanks @IrelDev, I actually had a similar problem with the frame size of `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, and assigning frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` with `updateUIViewController` helped solve my issue!

Comment: Actually I posted an answer to cover more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

If Asperi's answer did not work out for you, then it's probably as they said: the internal MyView layout has defects.

To resolve this matter, you have a couple options:

#### Option A. Use AutoLayout Constraints within `viewDidLoad`

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1. View Hierarchy
    self.addChild(self.mySubview)
    self.view.addSubview(self.mySubview.view)
    self.mySubview.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    // 2. View AutoLayout Constraints
    self.mySubview.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mySubview.view.leadingAnchor),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mySubview.view.trailingAnchor),
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mySubview.view.topAnchor),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mySubview.view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

#### Option B. Set frame manually within `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Simply within your `UIViewController`, set subviews frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1. Add your subviews once in `viewDidLoad`
    self.addChild(self.mySubview)
    self.view.addSubview(self.mySubview.view)
    self.mySubview.didMove(toParent: self)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // 2. Layout your subviews `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
    // Update subview frame size
    // Must be done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
    // Otherwise in `viewDidLoad` the bounds equal `UIScreen.main.bounds`, even if you used explicit frame within SwiftUI and used GeometryReader to pass the `CGSize` yourself to this UIViewController!
    let mySubviewFrame = self.view.bounds
    self.mySubview.view.frame = mySubviewFrame
}
```

#### Supplementary Resources

- Basically you have multiple layout methods in iOS. Here they are ordered from oldest/worst to newest/best. This ordering is opinionated of course:

  - **Frame-Based Layout**. Manually manipulate `frame` and `bounds` properties on the UIView.
  - **Auto-Resizing Masks**. Under the hood, an `autoResizingMask` uses archaic springs and struts. See [`autoResizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32455558/10830091), and [this article](https://www.thecodedself.com/autoresizing-masks/).
  - **AutoLayout [Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)**.
  - **AutoLayout [StackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html)**.
  - **SwiftUI's `VStack` and `HStack`**! This is only for SwiftUI and all the above applies to UIKit only.

<sub>Probably should have made a small dev article out of this.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One easy hack if you do not now what is wrong with MyView is to add it inside a UIView and then return it ie

```
public func makeUIView(context _: UIViewRepresentableContext< MyViewRepresentable>) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    let myView = MyView(frame: frame)
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    ])
    return view
}

public func updateUIView(_: UIView, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyViewRepresentable>) {}
```